# Search 2 "unrelated" Access tables with button click

Tags: c#

I have 2 tables in an Access database. Currently I have a c# winform app in VS 2015 with 2 forms that have a search button on each that will search that particular table The only similarity is the SerialNumber field but it is unrelated as the Serial Numbers for each table are for different equipment. Any tips on how to perform a search of both tables with 1 button?

```
private void searchItembtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(serialSearch.Text))
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.Transaction = transaction;
            command.Parameters.Add("@searchSerial", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = serialSearch.Text;
            string searchFB = "SELECT * FROM Inventory WHERE SerialNumber = @searchSerial";
            command.CommandText = searchFB;
            connection.Close();
            OleDbDataAdapter db = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            db.Fill(dt);
            dataGridFB.DataSource = dt;
        }
        catch (OleDbException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            connection.Close();
        }
        searchHide();
        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: make a union query in access, and use that as the rowsource in `searchFB` instead of `Inventory`. and btw, enclose `IDisposable`s in `using() { }` blocks, for example the data adapter, the command and the connection to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: Well I was reading up on the Union function but can seem to figure it out. Any way you can take my Query and get me started? My table names are Inventory and Competitive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a UNION query in Access, that will contain data from both tables:

```
SELECT
    SerialNumber,
    InventoryField1 AS Field1,
    InventoryFieldN AS FieldN
FROM Inventory

UNION ALL

SELECT
    SerialNumber,
    CompetitiveField1 AS Field1,
    CompetitiveFieldN AS FieldN
FROM Competitive
```

Then use this query as the row source in your command (CompetitiveInventory would be the query name):

```
string searchFB = "SELECT * FROM CompetitiveInventory WHERE SerialNumber=@searchSerial";
```

Alternatively, a `JOIN` may be what you want, depending on the requirement.

Comment: Well it seems that would work but......here is my FULL scenario. When the user does a search for a particular Serial Number in a table {from the form} it returns all of the information in that row pertaining to that serial number. So my idea is being able to search for a serial number from one place but searching 2 tables, then return the information for that serial number only.

Comment: I simply tried this as a test but it doesnt grab just the serial number you want, it grabs 'em all. -- string searchFB = "SELECT (SerialNumber) FROM Inventory UNION SELECT (SerialNumber) FROM Competitive WHERE (SerialNumber) = @searchSerial";

Comment: My proposal would mean to open the database in MS Access, create query, SQL view, paste the code of the UNION, save as "CompetitiveInventory" or whatever name you like, then use that query name instead of the table name in code. If you go with what you wrote in your comment above, you would need to include the WHERE clause twice: in both parts of the union after each SELECT.